# How to Quit current Powershell IE COM session using Try/Catch/Finally

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, com, try-catch-finally

Looking to terminate `IE COM Object` browser sessions at the end of my script, in my `Finally{}` statement.

I would think it be as simple as:

```
Finally{
    $ie.Quit()
}
```

But its not. the `$ie` object is unreachable at this stage in the script and no methods can be called on it. Anyone know why this is? Did the `$ie` object go out of scope?

I have defined the `$ie` object earlier, before my `Try{}` statement:

```
$ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application

Try{...}
```

But I dont actually Navigate() until inside the `Try{}` statement:

```
$ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application

    Try{
         $ie.navigate("http://www.allregs.com/tpl/Main.aspx")

}
```

Then I have my `catch{}` statement:

```
Catch{
   write-host “Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)” -ForegroundColor Red    
}
```

And lastly my `Finally{}` statement:

```
Finally{
    $ie.Quit() # 'can't call method on System.ComObject.' Null?
}
```

Any ideas why I can't `Quit()` the current `$ie` process at this stage in the script? Am I missing something? Is there another way to end the current Internet explorer session, without closing ALL of them? Any input welcome. Thanks.

**Update:**
So it appears `$IE` is unreachable at the end because the code never reaches the part where `$ie` actually navigates and gets a value. It only gets initialized at the start. In fact, it appears my `Invoke-Webrequest` requests (which log me in) are what prompt IE to start up and this is why a call to `$ie.Quit()` does nothing. My question now, is there a way to close IE sessions started using Invoke-Webrequest? `-UseBasicParameter` works to supress IE from starting up but it also messes up my code in weird ways so this doesn't seem like an option

Comment: It isn't clear whether you have the `$ie.Quit()` command in the `try{}` block, the `finally{}` block or both. If both, that's likely a problem...

Comment: Only in the Finally block

Comment: Revised my post to be more clear

Comment: I think you'll need to update your code samples to include more of what you are doing, including how you are using the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet.

Comment: see my other post @ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028778/how-to-close-ie-sessions-opened-by-invoke-webrequest?noredirect=1#comment61611849_37028778)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `finally{}` block unless there is something in the `catch{}` block that would terminate the script/function at that point. If the script/function is able to carry on after the `try{}catch{}`, then you can just call `$ie.Quit()`:

```
$ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application

try {
  $ie.navigate("http://www.allregs.com/tpl/Main.aspx")
}
catch {
  Write-Host “Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)” -ForegroundColor Red    
}

$ie.Quit()
```

### Update

In light of the additional information in the question, I don't think that try-catch-finally has anything to do with the actual problem here, so I guess the answer to the title question is that as long as **$ie** is still a valid application object, the `.Quit()` method will still work in a `finally{}` block.

Comment: Isn't the finally{} block necessary for cleanup? ref: [Why is try {…} finally {…} good; try {…} catch{} bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128818/why-is-try-finally-good-try-catch-bad?rq=1)

Comment: This is probably now beside the point for this question, but that link was about why using `catch{}` with *nothing* in the catch block is bad. In this case we are handling the Exception, albeit only with a `Write-Host` notification.

Comment: Ah okay. I will try to see if I can do without finally block.

Comment: Updated my post. $ie was not able to quit() because it was only initialized at the start and the code never reached the navigate(). In fact, it was the Invoke-WebRequests (that log my script in) which prompted IE to start and now I need to figure how to close them.

Comment: OK, so this is a red herring. Before I stop thinking about try-catch I'd just suggest that IF you are doing lots of things in a single try{}` block, maybe you should use multiple `try{} catch{}` constructions around those commands that might throw a terminating error, or even a single `trap{}` at the top instead. I'll let you read up on that yourself. ;-)

Comment: Just saw your other question. I would DEFINITELY look to limit the `try{}` block to just those lines where you need it, else you still have a bit of work on your hands working out which line threw an error.