# How to close IE sessions opened by Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, dom, webrequest

I am noticing in my script that `Invoke-WebRequest` is launching Internet Explorer (presumably to parse the DOM). Is there a way to close down these IE sessions at the end of my script, for cleanup purposes?

The line highlighted in red is the `iwr` which prompts Internet Explorer to open. If I add `-UseBasicParsing` to that $AllRegs request, the script fails a couple lines later, trying to capture `$LibraryID`
[image]

Comment: I would think to just use `-UseBasicParsing` so IE never launches in the first place. However, doing this for whatever reason this causes my succeeding requests to fail.

Comment: Are you invoking the script through PowerShell ISE or through the console host? I would think once the host application closes, the IE instances would close as well, and I'd recommend not trying to force them (so as not to interfere with any other unrelated IE instances).

Comment: Invoking with PowerShell ISE (as admin). The IE windows remain open even after closing the ISE

Comment: Are they actual interactive IE windows or just processes? What version of PowerShell? Are the `iwr` calls successful?

Comment: Hmm, how can I tell if they are "actual interactive IE windows or just processes".  Powershell v 4.0. The `iwr` are sucessful so long as I don't add `-UseBasicParameter`

Comment: I mean can you see visible windows in the taskbar, that you can click on and interact with, or do you just see `iexplore.exe` processes in task manager?

Comment: Oh. Yes they are visible windows that I can click and interact with

Comment: That's interesting to me.. when I use `iwr` (without `-UseBasicParsing`), not only do I not see IE windows, I don't see `iexplore.exe` processes either (they could be instantiated and destroyed faster than I can see them in task manager, but I've tried several times and don't see any). I'm on PS5 on Win10, but I don't recall seeing browser windows in past iterations either.

Comment: Could it be because one of my `iwr` opens a link in a new tab, thus perhaps forcing an IE window to open?

Comment: While the DOM is parsed, JS is not executed so I'm not sure how that could happen.

Comment: Hmm. Going to add some of my code to OP.

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166426/powershell-invoke-webrequest-youll-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-about

Answer (score 0):

To forcefully close all IE sessions use:

```
get-process iexplore | stop-process
```

To more gracefully close IE sessions use:

```
Get-Process iexplore | ForEach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() }
```

You can also add a wait after the ForEach call, but I use the same line for shutting Chrome down & it has never been necessary.