# When will a Try and Catch statement break you out of Try?

Tags: powershell, try-catch, try-catch-finally

If I have multiple Codelines within a Try statement.

will it break me out as soon as 1 of them doesn't function?/through an error?

and if yes, will it ignore the rest of the code within the try statement that is written after the error?

**Update:**

I found this Thread which basically explains it as well [Why is try {…} finally {…} good; try {…} catch{} bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128818/why-is-try-finally-good-try-catch-bad?rq=1)

Comment: It depends on what type of error it comes across. The only exceptions that are caught, are the ones that are from *terminating* errors. Non-terminating errors will continue. You can also else specify when a command show be terminating using `-ErrorAction Stop`, or assigning *Stop* to the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable from the beginning, making every error terminating

Comment: If the error is terminating, then the code after the throwing statement inside the `try` block will be skipped, yes.